# Devicecheck Expo bare workflow

Tags: react-native, expo, devicecheck

I'm struggling with how to implement/use devicecheck and app attest on iOS with expo bare workflow.

I googled a lot with no luck. The only thing I found was this git repo: https://github.com/dayitv89/react-native-ios11-devicecheck

But I couldn't get it to work. Anyone has any example on how to implement this?
Even with RN, no problem I can use RN without expo ..

Thanks in advance!